# Scrape with HTML agility pack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I scraped web pages with `HTML agility pack`
but I down know how to grab data which load with javascript.
I know `ChromeDriver` could be helpful, but I don't want to open the browser in my application. actually, I want the program to grab data behind the user interface.
For instance, I want to grab all slider images in this [page](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/paratype/lehmann-egyptian/)
but images load by JS. So HTML agility pack is not able to catch it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can also use headless chromedriver. A headless browser is a great tool for automated testing and server environments where you don’t need a visible UI shell.

Chrome Headless is supported from Chrome 59.x and above.

you can use chrome headless using this code

```
  ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
  option.AddArgument("--headless");
  _driver = new ChromeDriver(option);
```